# ipdb displaying ansi color escape sequences

Tags: realgud, ansi

I'm trying to set up realgud using ipdb with emacs. The problem is that the following is displayed at the command prompt (running `realgud:ipdb`): [6n[Jipdb> [6D[6C[6D[J[6n[Jipdb> [6D[6C

From googling around, I came across various links that I think explain what the problem is, but the solutions therein didn't fix my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094855/visible-ansi-escape-sequences-when-running-emacs-shell-these-are-not-ansi-color

[Why does *compilation* buffer show control characters?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8135/why-does-compilation-buffer-show-control-characters)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK this is a known bug in Emacs since IPython 5.1.0. Please file another bug report, so raising its weight.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I applied the fix at this link: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5 but it only fixes the ipython interpreter shell, not the ipdb shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update, I managed to fix the problem by adding the following into an executable file in my PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipython --simple-prompt -i -c "%run -d $@"
```

Then in emacs when running `realgud:ipdb`, when asked what command to use, just switch out `ipdb` with whatever you name the executable file.

On OS X you will need the following package though: https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: --simple-promt avoids the garbage but doesn't allow multiline-input :(

Comment: Yeah it's not really a fix I guess, just a workaround.

Comment: I will file a bug report when I get a chance.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
ipython --simple-prompt -i -c "%run -d $@" -->thanks it works for me. emacs25.2+ spacemacs settting+ipython 6.2.1+ ipdb 0.10

Answer (score 0):

in spacemacs, add the [`shell`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btools/shell) layer, will solve this problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Commit [b8b587b](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/commit/b8b587be28e15b3a053482ff9848d4259e40f13d) of Nov 26, 2018 may fix this.